# Adding 4-dimensional vector that can be used in Nodes [bpy]

Tags: python, node-editor, shader-nodes

Is it possible to create a data type such that I can create custom nodes that take it as input/output? What I'm specifically trying to create is a 4-dimensional vector since that will make a lot of the math and data management easier for me.
Alternatively, is there a way I can edit the default vector type to have 4 dimensions rather then 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own node system, like the [Animation Nodes](https://animation-nodes.com/) add-on, and there you'd have a complete freedom on the types of sockets. There's a **Custom Nodes** template in the scripting tab, that will get you started:

[image]

However, if by a *Custom Node* you mean a *node group*, or if you mean a custom node but one that is able to operate inside a geo-nodes, compositor or shader node tree, then what you're asking for is impossible, because those systems are programmed in C and the implementation doesn't support custom types.

In all three default node systems, whenever there's a need for an array of 4 values, be it an RGBA color, or 4d vector, the array is simply split into a color/vector, and a separate fourth value (alpha / W):

[image]

[image]

[image]

So this is what I recommend that you do... Just split your input sockets and output sockets into Vector + W scalar.

You could perhaps hack the node trees to display a single vector socket, and yet behind the scenes create an additional hidden link with the fourth value, but that would be misleading to the users...

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll look into making custom node groups with split sockets like you mentioned, since I'm trying to make this work in the Shader Editor currently.